# Javascript: Unexpected <li>

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am using Javascript and Flask to make a "voting" system. (using socketio)

The code is:

`application.py`

```py
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)
votes = {"yes": 0, "no": 0, "maybe": 0}

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on("submit vote")
def vote(data):
    selection = data["selection"]
    votes[selection] +=1
    print(votes)
    emit("announce vote", {"now": votes}, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Vote</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class = "table" id="votes">
            <tr>
                <th scope = "col">#</th>
                <th scope = "col">Number of votes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope = "col">Yes</th>
                <td id = "votes-yes">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope = "col">No</th>
                <td id = "votes-no">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope = "col">Maybe</th>
                <td id = "votes-maybe">0</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type = "button" data-vote="yes">Yes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type = "button" data-vote="no">No</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type = "button" data-vote="maybe">Maybe</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

`index.js`(in static)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    // When connected, configure buttons
    socket.on('connect', () => {

        // Each button should emit a "submit vote" event
        document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
            button.onclick = () => {
                const selection = button.dataset.vote;
                socket.emit('submit vote', {'selection': selection});
            };
        });
    });

    socket.on('announce vote', data => {
        var votes_now = data["now"];
        document.querySelector('#votes-yes').innerHTML = votes_now[yes];
        document.querySelector('#votes-no').innerHTML = votes_now[no];
        document.querySelector('#votes-maybe').innerHTML = votes_now[maybe];
    });
});
```

When I click the button, it should emit a submit vote event, then add 1 to the dictionary in the Flask system, then broadcast a message back to Javascript, incrementing the values in the table.

But instead, after emitting a submit vote event, and adding 1 to the dictionary, and broadcasting a message, instead a `<li>` tag appears with "Vote Recorded: undefined". What is the problem?

[image: here's what the <code><li></code> tags look like]

Comment: Where does `Vote Recorded` text come from?

Comment: sorry, the  `<li>` I entered turned to a bullet point. I reedited it.

Comment: I don't see `Vote Recorded` anywhere in your code or html output template.  Where is the error message `Vote Recorded: undefined` coming from?

Comment: I have been working with something that produces a `<li>` with a similar message recently with the same file, but I believe that I removed/ changed them all.

Comment: maybe socketio "remember"ed what I said?